# Why is todays date is shown as before date?

Tags: java, date

Why is today's date shown as before date ?

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

        Date date = new Date();

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        List currentObject = new ArrayList();

        currentObject.add("2012-09-27");
        Date ExpDate = dateFormat.parse((String) currentObject.get(0));

        if (ExpDate.before(date)) {
            System.out.println("true");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Because we're after 2012-09-27 at 0h...

Comment: Try printing out the value of `date` and the value of `ExpDate` and you'll see why `ExpDate` is before `date`.

Comment: You just needed to do a **Select all** and **Ctrl** **+** **K**, to format it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Date date = new Date();
```

will yield the time too, but this

```
currentObject.add("2012-09-27");
dateFormat.parse((String) currentObject.get(0));
```

will default to `00:00:00`, as your `dateFormat` excludes the time thus causing the time-part to be set to `0h`.

So it's correct:

```
ExpDate: 2012-09-27 00:00:00
```

*is* earlier than

```
date: 2012-09-27 <some time later than midnight>
```

Comment: Date date = new Date();
Date ExpDate = dateFormat.parse((String) currentObject.get(0));

if (ExpDate .before(date)) 

must return false

Comment: means for  current date before must return false.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

`Date date = new Date();`

You are creating a Date object for the instant that is created, i.e. 27 September 2012 11:59:01.01.

This is after the date you created earlier, which had no specified **time** component, and therefore defaulted to 00:00:00.000.